# isPrime returns different result for the same value?

Tags: java, arrays, primes

This is a program that determines whether an element in an array of 10 numbers is prime or not. The prime ones will be replaced by -1 and the others remain the same when printing.

It seems fine to me, but when I run my code with 9s, some will get -1 which means 9 is a prime(wrong), some returns 9(as not prime). Why am I encountering this? Can someone help please

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question5{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int [10];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter your number " + i);
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Before method: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        prime(array);
        System.out.println("After the method: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();


    }

    public static void prime(int[] list){
        boolean isPrime = true;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++){
                count = i;
                if (list[i] % j == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (list [i] == 0 || list[i] == 1){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (list [i] == 2){
                    isPrime = true;
                    list[count] = -1;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime){
                list[count] = -1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your second for-loop should be `j < list[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three errors:

1. You are updating list[count] instead of list[i]
2. The condition of the inner loop is wrong. It should be `j < list[i]` or `j *j <= list[i]`
3. Your code identifies `0` and `1` as primes, which is incorrect. You should test `if (list [i] == 0 || list[i] == 1)` prior to the inner loop.

The code should look like this:

```
public static void prime(int[] list){
    boolean isPrime = true;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        isPrime = true;
        if (i < 2) {
          isPrime = false;
        } else {
            for (int j = 2; j * j <= list[i]; j++){
                count = i;
                if (list[i] % j == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (list [i] == 2){
                    isPrime = true;
                    list[i] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isPrime){
            list[i] = -1;
        }

    }
}
```

For example:

```
Enter your number 0
0
Enter your number 1
1
Enter your number 2
2
Enter your number 3
3
Enter your number 4
4
Enter your number 5
5
Enter your number 6
6
Enter your number 7
7
Enter your number 8
8
Enter your number 9
9
Before method: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
After the method: 
0 1 -1 -1 4 -1 6 -1 8 9
```

Comment: I think checking prime for the condition of x = 1 and 0 can actually be put in the for-loop. It needs a break; to break the for-loop

Answer (score 1):

The main logical problem which jumps out at me right away is that you are not checking for primes correctly.  You should be iterating in a loop from 2 until the particular number in the array, checking for divisors.  Instead, you iterate from 2 until the length of the list.  Try this version:

```
public static void prime(int[] list) {
    for (int i=0; i < list.length; ++i) {
         int num = list[i];
         boolean isPrime;
         if (num == 1) {
             isPrime = false;
         }
         else {
             isPrime = true;
         }

         for (int j=2; j <= Math.sqrt(num); ++j) {
             if (num % j == 0) {
                 isPrime = false;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if (isPrime) {
             list[i] = -1;
         }
    }

    return;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    prime(list);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
}
```

The above `main()` printed:

```
[1, -1, -1, 4, -1, 6, -1, 8, 9, 10]
```